# Best Image Processing technique for detecting smudges/residues

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to Image Processing and I am currently undertaking a Master's project that aims to deliver an application which replicates the effect of [smudge attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smudge_attack) for forensic purposes.

In order to do so, I have created an Android app that can capture images and apply Canny Edge operator to the captured images. However, I am not able to get the contour of the smudges with this technique, and I don't really know what are the other viable options.

I would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me with their expertise. Many thanks in advance!

**Note**: I am using OpenCV for this project, which is also something new to me

Comment: that's how getting a master degree looks like

Comment: Hope, this helps http://www.cs.uml.edu/~xinwenfu/paper/VisionBasedAttack_Fu_2014.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately (or fortunately, for most people), recovering oil smudge patterns from a smartphone screen using visible light photography is not going to be very reliable, and OpenCV isn't a silver bullet that will help you with that. You may be able to adjust the contrast, brightness, or amplify certain channels of the photograph to highlight features that weren't visible before. However, blindly applying Canny edge detection or any other operator available in OpenCV is unlikely to reveal some "invisible ink" to you unless you have some goal in mind and some understanding of what the operator is intended to do.

More information can be found in the papers referenced by the Wikipedia article, but I imagine the most important factor in seeing smudges is going to be the lighting setup when the photo was taken. It might also be possible to detect smudges with less optimal lighting if your photo sensor was detecting some wavelength other than visible light, though that is pure speculation on my part. Ultimately, if the smudge information is not present in the photo because of specific lighting or wavelengths captured, though, you will not be able to extract it with any sort of image processing.

Your best bet is to read the OpenCV docs, and [follow some of their tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html), which are excellent. There is also [great support for the Python bindings](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This will be good for you as a Masters student and also give you a much better idea of what OpenCV can, and cannot do for you.

Comment: Hi Andy,
thanks for your answer. Actually I fiddled around with the parameters and took some high quality images and was able to get something.